# Android, Open Front and Back Cameras Simultaneously with 2 SurfaceView,but the second CameraDevice.StateCallback onError ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE

Tags: android, android-camera2

Open Front and Back Cameras Simultaneously with 2 SurfaceView,but the second  CameraDevice.StateCallback onError ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE;
[image]

how to break through ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE?  some android device can both to open Front and Back Cameras; but many android device can't; I think the manufacturer don't lift restriction.